Realizar una búsqueda en un archivo binario en C mediante acceso directo
De un archivo con datos separados por punto y coma (;) con la siguiente estructura:
09001;52;29;3;40;1;8
09007;7;51;5;0;0;2
....
El primer valor de cada registro es un identificador único y el resto son valores métricos.
Con esta información creo un archivo binario mediante lenguaje C en el que cada valor es un int, por lo tanto cada registro son 7*sizeof(int).
Ahora bien, intento crear una función que introduciendo un identificador, por ejemplo el 09007, y haciendo uso del archivo binario, consiga colocar el puntero de lectura en la posición correspondiente al registro 09007 por medio de acceso directo.
No consigo relacionar el 09007 con la segunda posición que ocupa en la lista de registros.
Gracias de antemano.

Puedes mostrar el código?
